# Change the Share Site Email Template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any way to change the Share Site invitation email?

Answer (score -2):

There doesn't appear to be an OOTB solution. This came up in my search:

http://blog.tahoepartners.com/index.php/customize-sharepoint-welcome-email-adding-users-granting-permissions/

(May require some basic development understanding on the topics JQuery, SharePoint 2013 Client side libraries)

Comment: You need to quote the main aspects of the arcticle as the links tend to go down.

Comment: The answer won't work anyways.  You cannot modify application pages in SharePoint Online.